# SQL Server : do not Select all if true

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have these columns

```
Id  Status
----------
 1  pass
 1  fail
 2  pass
 3  pass
```

How do I select all that only have a status of `pass` but if the `Id` has at least one fail it will not be selected as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If same id can have multiple passes

```
SELECT id
from table 
WHERE status = 'pass' 
and id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE status = 'fail')
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much! I was having trouble because its not working even though the logic is correct. turns out the inner SELECT returns some nulls so I just needed to  add IS NOT NULL. thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `GROUP BY` & `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT Id  
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Id
HAVING Sum(case when status ='pass' then 1 else 0 end) = count(status)
```

`HAVING` clause can be changed to

```
HAVING Count(case when status ='pass' then 1 end) = count(status)
```

Comment: what if one (or more) of  the status value is NULL?

Comment: I would prefer this rather than going for a sub query, +1 from my side

Comment: I do too. +1. Just changing counting false and check that it is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I just hate chatty case statement, so

```
SELECT Id
FROM table1
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Status]) = 1 AND MIN([Status]) = 'pass'
```

or

```
SELECT Id
FROM table1
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(NULLIF([Status], 'fail')) = 1 AND COUNT(NULLIF([Status], 'pass')) = 0
```

The second query only works when status has two values 'pass' and 'fail'.